# In abelian categories, prove some properties in $R$-$Mod$

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

I’m sorry if this is not a good problem.

I know if $$(Coker\ \ f) \circ g=0$$ in $R$-$Mod$, then g can factor as $$g=f \circ h$$(not uniquely). Now I want to prove this in abelian categories,but I don’t know how to prove it except using Mitchell’s embedding theorem.

How can I prove it in abelian categories not using Mitchell’s embedding theorem (only arrow)?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I'm not sure I believe this...

Comment: coker(f ° g) or coker(f) ° g? Makes a difference

Comment: @FoscoLoregian have been changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely not true in all categories of $R$-modules; in fact it is false in the category of abelian groups. Indeed, $\operatorname{coker}(f)\circ id=0$ as soon as $f$ is an epimorphism, but a factorisation $id=f\circ h$ only exists if $f$ is a split epimorphism. There are a lot of epimorphisms of abelian groups that are not split, for example the projections $\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ for $n\geq 2$.

Your confusion probably comes from the fact that it *is* true in the category of vector spaces (over any field); but you need bases to prove this.

Comment: After checking my thoughts,I found it may be true when f is monomorphism,for bijection is isomorphism in abelian categories (Tōhoku), which made me confusion in this problem.

Comment: @Greahcle If $f$ is a monomorphism, it is the kernel of its cokernel, so of course in that case it is true.